# Error al cargar datos

Tags: android-studio

esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien de salud, soy nuevo en estas lides de android studio ya termine mi proyecto en java y el mismo quiero llevarlo a android, pero ya me encontré con problema cuando quiero cargar los datos en un spinner (que es es un combox) no lorealiza, en este caso necesito que me muestre los ID que son los campos claves de casa caso en particular, les presente la prueba que estaba haciendo.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Spinner spcodigo;
private AsyncHttpClient cliente;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    spcodigo = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spcodigo);
    cliente = new AsyncHttpClient();
    llenarSpinner();
}

private void llenarSpinner(){
    String url = "http://192.168.1.96/oficina/buscar_casos.php";
    cliente.post(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            if (statusCode == 200){
                cargarSpinner(new String(responseBody));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

        }
    });
}

private void cargarSpinner (String respuesta) {
    ArrayList<Casos> lista = new ArrayList<Casos>();
    try {
        JSONArray jsonarreglo = new JSONArray (respuesta);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarreglo.length(); i++){
            Casos c = new Casos();
            c.setID(jsonarreglo.getJSONObject(i).getInt("ID"));
            lista.add(c);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<Casos> a = new ArrayAdapter<Casos>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, lista);
        spcodigo.setAdapter(a);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

ojala que me puedan ayudar en este problema, no me arroja ningún error en el código realizado, pienso que el error puede ser algo de lógica, creo que el error puede ser con el string de la url, que no lo encuentra me imagino, pero al hacer las pruebas con el postmann esta muy bien y no arroja error tampoco, desde ya muchas gracias.

este es el código que se utiliza en PHP, primero el de la conexión:

```
<?php
function retornarConexion(){
$_SERVER ="localhost";
$usuario ="hector";
$clave ="";
$base = "oficina";
$con = mysqli_connect ($_SERVER, $usuario, $clave, $base) or die ("Problemas");
mysqli_set_charset ($con, "UTF8");
return $con;
}
?>
```

y este es el código que se utiliza para la búsqueda de los datos.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
require("conexion1.php");
$conexion = retornarConexion();
$datos = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT   ID,Fecha_Denuncia,Fecha_Siniestro,N_Siniestro,Descripcion,Nombre_Conducto
r,Rut_Conductor,Patente_Vehiculo,Nombre_Tercero,Patente_Tercero,
Nombre_Compania,Inspeccion,Nombre_Asegurado,Rut_Asegurado,N_Poliza,Tipo_S
eguro,Analista,Perdida,Fecha_Designacion,Monto_Perdida,Fecha_Informe,Insp
ector,Activo from casos where ID=$_GET[ID]");
$resultado = mysqli_fetch_all($datos, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($resultado);
?>
```

**Error:**

```
org.json.JSONException: Value {"casos":[{"id":"1","Denuncia":"01\/09\/2022","Siniestro":"30\/08\/2022","Numero":"398123456"}]}
```

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo te informo que no muestra nada, ningún dato incluido, estuve hasta cinco minutos por si acaso se demoraba en cargar los datos dentro del spinner (ID) nada, he hecho de todo y nada, no se si el código esta malo o en la clase esta malo, no lo se como soy nuevo en estas lides aprendo cada día cosas nuevas y disculpa las molestias

Comment: amigos favor de ayudarme, estuve realizando de nuevo el cargar el spinner con los datos del ID, en todo lo que he visto a través del Internet lo hacen con campos que son string, pero en este caso en particular debe ser un int para la búsqueda, ahora realice un debug y me arroja este error "cliente=no such instance field:cliente", lo que dice que no encuentra cliente, pero si lo ven en el código esta bien declarado y no da error alguno favor de verlo y desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo por tu consulta de las librerías que se utilizan en build.gradle app o las que te menciono en el encabezado de mi consulta, realice el try catch y no arroja tampoco ningún error al momento de ejecutarlo, ahora lo realice con el debug y me aparece esto "Connected to the target, VM: address: 'localhost.51800', transport, 'Socket', el punto de interrupción lo realice en esta linea de comando "String url = "http://192.168.1.86/oficina/buscar_casos.php";", favor de tenerme paciencia soy nuevo en estas lides de android studio y me gusta aprender, desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo te cuneto que tralice otro breakpoint y me arroja este error, cliente = No such instance 'field; cliente'

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo te cuento que ya lo había realizado y no realiza nada y manda el mensaje de error antes descritos, si gustas coloco las imágenes de la tabla de la base de datos que estoy utilizando. Por otro lado, te pido mis disculpas por no contestar antes, ya que me encontraba con problemas personales

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo lo hice como me lo mencionaste y te envió los errores que me señala, y al parecer este es el error "2022-09-24 17:34:35.567 4983-4983/com.example.prueba1 W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {"casos":[]} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray", en postmann funciona bien y en android no se porque y desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo lo realice y me arroja este error ahora: org.json.JSONException: Value {"casos":[{"id":"1","Denuncia":"01\/09\/2022","Siniestro":"30\/08\/2022","Numero":"398123456"}]} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray, por lo menos me muestra algo, pero no carga el ID en el spinner

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo muy buenas te cuento que me funciono, cambie el código en php y me funciono ok, ,muchas gracias por tu ayuda y comprensión ya que soy nuevo en estas lides, ahora con el problema del spinner que al escoger un campo quiero que me los muestre en las cajas de texto y no me funciona, me da problemas con los permisos y otras cosas, así que estoy investigando como se hace y se soluciona

Comment: ¡Que bueno que hayas podido solucionar tu problema! Te recomiendo que cierres la pregunta votando mi respuesta. Y si tienes dudas o inconvenientes, recuerda que puedes abrir otra pregunta :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien, como bien sugiere el error, el problema es `2022-09-24 17:34:35.567 4983-4983/com.example.prueba1 W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {"casos":[]} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray` por lo que deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```
private void cargarSpinner (String respuesta) {
    Casos c = new Casos();
    ArrayList<Casos> lista = new ArrayList<Casos>();
    try {
        JSONArray jsonarreglo = new JSONArray (respuesta);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarreglo.length(); i++){
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonarreglo.getJSONObject(i);//crea un json de tipo JSONObject
            int ID = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject1.getString("ID"));
            lista.add(new Casos(ID));
        }
        ArrayAdapter<Casos> a = new ArrayAdapter<Casos>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, lista);
        spcodigo.setAdapter(a);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Todo eso suponiendo que tienes dentro de tu clase Casos tienes un constructor así:

```
public Casos (int ID){ this.ID = ID;}
```

En el caso de que no, puedes modificar estas línea:

```
            int ID = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject1.getString("ID"));
            lista.add(new Casos(ID));
```

Por estas:

```
        c.setID(jsonObject1.getInt("ID"));
        lista.add(c);
```

Dime si te funciona :D